# Social media spreadsheet

Tags: facebook, youtube, google-sheets, instagram, social-media

I'd first like to apologize for my english which is not my mother tongue and also if my question might be stupid, I'm not a developer and hope you guys will be able to help me.

I'm actually looking to build a Google spreadsheet to use is as a social media dashboard. The point is to have in one page all the likes, follower, etc. for my different client.

I found on this forum the Instagram formula which is:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(CONCATENATE(IMPORTDATA(B1)),"(^.*followed_by: {""count"": )(\d+)(}.*)","$2")
```

and it works pefectly.

For Facebook I've found:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.facebook.com/nameofthepage/","//span[@id='PagesLikesCountDOMID']")
```

it does work but takes about 5 minutes to show the count of likes and this is every time I open the spreadsheet. Before that I just get N/A.

YouTube works perfectly with:

```
=MID(QUERY(IMPORTXML(F1,"//div[@class='primary-header-actions']"),"select Col1"),31,20)
```

But for the others (Twitter, LinkedIn, Pinterest, etc.) I haven't been able to find something that works correctly.

Does anyone have already done this job? And would it be possible for the Facebook formula to work faster?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Mike

Comment: This is basically scraping, and that is against Facebook’s ToS to begin with. If you want any such information from Facebook, you should use their API. That’s gonna be a bit more complex though, so you will probably need an actual developer.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if I am way off here, but I just happened upon this and figured it wouldn't hurt to post it to see if it helps. (I am a novice)

=IMPORTXML("https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name="&A3, "//a/@href[contains(.,'"&A2&"' )]")

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rwLwhjIRLdWJJbv7bUf_JFUdlHWSar4lZZ8GUJGzF3M/edit?usp=sharing